# ERROR: expected declaration or statement within else if statements

Tags: javascript, expression, declaration

```
if (shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth > 29)  (shirtLength >29) && (shirtSleeve > 8.38); {
    console.log("S");    
    } else if (shirtWidth >= 19 && shirtWidth == 22)  (shirtLength == 29) && (shirtSleeve > 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38); {
    console.log("M");    
    } else if (shirtWidth >= 21 && shirtWidth == 23)  (shirtLength === 30) && (shirtSleeve > 8.38 && shirtSleeve == 8.87); {
    console.log("L");    
    } else if (shirtWidth <22 && shirtWidth == 25)  (shirtLength === 31) && (shirtSleeve < 8.63 && shirtSleeve == 9.62); {
    console.log("XL");    
    } else if (shirtWidth < 24 && shirtWidth == 29)  (shirtLength === 34) && (shirtSleeve < 9.63 && shirtSleeve == 10.12); {
    console.log("2XL");    
    } else if (shirtWidth < 26  && shirtWidth == 23)  (shirtLength === 30) && (shirtSleeve < 10.13 && shirtSleeve ==12.00); {
    console.log("3XL");    
    }
```

If you cant already tell, im very new to JavaScript. I can't seem to find a solution to this error, with my else if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code tho this, you have done it wrong

```
if ((shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth > 29) || (shirtLength >29 && shirtSleeve > 8.38) ){
      console.log("S");    
} else if( (shirtWidth >= 19 && shirtWidth == 22) || (shirtLength == 29 && shirtSleeve > 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38)){
    console.log("M");    
} else if ((shirtWidth >= 21 && shirtWidth == 23) || (shirtLength === 30 && shirtSleeve > 8.38 && shirtSleeve == 8.87)){
    console.log("L");    
} else if ((shirtWidth <22 && shirtWidth == 25) || (shirtLength === 31 && shirtSleeve < 8.63 && shirtSleeve == 9.62)) {
    console.log("XL");    
} else if ((shirtWidth < 24 && shirtWidth == 29) || (shirtLength === 34 && shirtSleeve < 9.63 && shirtSleeve == 10.12)) {
    console.log("2XL");    
} else if((shirtWidth < 26  && shirtWidth == 23) || (shirtLength === 30 && shirtSleeve < 10.13 && shirtSleeve ==12.00)) {
    console.log("3XL");    
}
```

Comment: You are missing an `else if` in the last condition